# parse multiple lines in perl regular expression and extract value

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I am a beginner in perl. I have a text file with text similar to as below. i need to extract VALUE="<**NEEDED VALUE**>". Say for SPINACH, i should be getting SALAD alone.

How to use perl regex to get the value. i need to parse multiple lines to get it. ie between each #ifonly --- #endifonly

> $cat check.txt

```
while (<$file>)
{
   if (m/#ifonly .+ SPINACH .+ VALUE=(")([\w]*)(") .+ #endifonly/g)
{
    my $chosen = $2;
   }
}
```

```
#ifonly APPLE CARROT SPINACH
VALUE="SALAD" REQUIRED="yes" 
QW RETEWRT OIOUR
#endifonly
#ifonly APPLE MANGO ORANGE CARROT
VALUE="JUICE" REQUIRED="yes" 
as df fg
#endifonly
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
   my $rc = /#ifonly .+ SPINACH/ .. (my ($value) = /VALUE="([^"]*)"/);
   next unless $rc =~ /E0$/;
   say $value;
}

__DATA__
#ifonly APPLE CARROT SPINACH
VALUE="SALAD" REQUIRED="yes" 
QW RETEWRT OIOUR
#endifonly
#ifonly APPLE MANGO ORANGE CARROT
VALUE="JUICE" REQUIRED="yes" 
as df fg
#endifonly
```

This uses a small trick described by brian d foy [here](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/11/make-exclusive-flip-flop-operators/). As the link describes, it uses the scalar [range operator / flipflop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

Comment: Also, somewhat shorter:
next unless (/#ifonly .+ SPINACH/ .. (my ($value) = /VALUE="([^"]*)"/)) =~ /E0$/; But frankly, it breaks my indent, so I wouldn't use it. : ) There's also quite a bit going on there, which may not be the best for maintainability.

Comment: Pretty cool approach, and (once more) the link you posted has taught me something, so thanks for that!

Comment: @canavanin I have the links. All of them! You are welcome - the Effective Perler is my favorite Perl blog, so it's always a pleasure to direct people there.

Answer (score 1):

In case your file is very big (or you want to read it line by line for some other reason) you could do it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($file, $keyword);

# now get command line options (see Usage note below)
GetOptions(
            "f=s" => \$file,
            "k=s" => \$keyword,
          );

# if either the file or the keyword has not been provided, display a
# help text and exit
if (! $file || ! $keyword) {
   print STDERR<<EOF;

   Usage: script.pl -f filename -k keyword

EOF
   exit(1);
}

my $found;         # indicator that the keyword has been found
my $returned_word; # will store the word you want to retrieve

open FILE, "<$file" or die "Cannot open file '$file': $!";
while (<FILE>) {
   if (/$keyword/) {
      $found = 1;
   }

   # the following condition will be true between all lines that
   # start with '#ifonly' or '#endifonly' - but only if the keyword 
   # has been found!
   if (/^#ifonly/ .. /^#endifonly/ && $found) {
      if (/VALUE="(\w+)"/) { 
         $returned_word = $1;
         print "looking for $keyword --> found $returned_word\n";

         last; # if you want to get ALL values after the keyword
               # remove the 'last' statement, as it makes the script
               # exit the while loop
      }
   }
}
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file contents in a string and then search for the pattern in the string:

```
my $file;    
$file.=$_ while(<>);    
if($file =~ /#ifonly.+?\bSPINACH\b.+?VALUE="(\w*)".+?#endifonly/s) {
        print $1;
}
```

Your original regex needs some tweaking:

- You need to make your quantifiers
  non-greedy.
- Use the `s` modifier to make `.`
  match newline as-well.

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/dieoM)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer based on the flip-flop operator:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<$file>)
{
  if ( (/^#ifonly.*\bSPINACH\b/ .. /^#endifonly/) &&
       (my ($chosen) = /^VALUE="(\w+)"/) )
  {
    say $chosen;
  }
}
```

This solution applies the second test to *all* of the lines in the range.  The trick @Hugmeir used to exclude the start and end lines isn't needed because the "inner" regex, `/^VALUE="(\w+)"/`, can never match them anyway (I added the `^` anchor to all regexes to make doubly sure of that).

Answer (score 0):

These two lines in one answer given two days ago

```
my $file;
$file.=$_ while(<>);
```

are not very efficient. Perl will likely read the file in big chunks, break those chunks into lines of text for the `<>` and then the `.=` will join those lines back to make a big string. It would be more efficient to slurp the file. The basic style is to alter `\$` the input record separator.

```
undef $/;
$file = <>;
```

The module `File::Slurp;` (see `perldoc File::Slurp`) may be even better.